# Inspecting tensorflow's .data, .meta, and .index

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have been trying, for a couple of weeks now, to use multiple neural networks that I've found on GitHub. Most of the time these repos contain a folder with .meta, .index, and .data files. I first want to inspect these neural networks using TensorBoard(or any other tool), and then use them propertly.

So far I have tried converting these files to .pb, and then use this file in tensor board. But ofcourse this approach has not worked.

I have made some assumptions in this process:
1) I'm running the latest TensorFlow (py3) docker container on macOS.
2) I'm assuming that for just inspecting a file I do not require the necessary hardware that a network might need.

For converting these files to .pb, I've used the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

meta_path = '/Users/emiliovazquez/Documents/Fall2019/cs594/Final/models/triviaqa-unfiltered-shared-norm/best-weights/best-202000.meta' # Your .meta file
output_node_names = [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]   # Output nodes

with tf.Session() as sess:
 # Restore the graph
 saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)

 # Load weights
 saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/emiliovazquez/Documents/Fall2019/cs594/Final/models/triviaqa-unfiltered-shared-norm/best-weights/best-202000'))

 # Freeze the graph
 frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess,
    sess.graph_def,
    output_node_names)

 # Save the frozen graph
 with open('./output_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

To inspect the generated .pb file I've used [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py) repo and made the appropriate changes to run on the latest TensorFlow version.

However, after running this second python file propertly, the process exits with and error. OS did not find the file specified. However, I tried with both relative and absolute paths inside the container .

Please let me know what information I'm missing, what tool I should use, or whether the given approach is correct

Answer (score 0):

It'd be better if you showed your Docker files, but from what your question shows, you haven't sent the Python files to the Docker machine. If the Python file has been sent, then you haven't specified the path to the output file correctly. Since this is running in Docker, you can't use an absolute path for your computer, you'll have to use a relative path so that it works on both your machine and in Docker.

Comment: I have actually included the file inside my docker container. I'll edit the question to add a reference to my docker container.